# Adjust UILabel position up based on previous UITextView content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uilabel, uitextview

I want to make an bubble view design more or like `WhatsApp` design. Please check the attached `WhatsApp` screenshot,

In screen **Time label** (1.12 PM and 5.16 PM) adjusts its **Y** position based on text message content. Its adjustable based on last line content (if the last line is not fully filled, its moves up slightly and it reduces bubble height - looks good).

Is there any solution/suggestion? How to know, Is UITextview content takes fully last line or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks!

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Give the cell's height based on the UILabel's height in heightFor delegate method.

Comment: The lable needs to be dynamic in nature, and should not be textview. The height should be dynamic according to the width of the label. Label should be over the view (named as Backview). Then this can all be managed in the table view cell

Comment: Thanks both of you!, so we need to handle in single label (message and timestamp)?